# How to connect to a database outside a function, disconnect inside a function, and then reconnect inside that function with R & RMySQL

Tags: r, function, database-connection, scoping, rmysql

I have an R script utilizing the RMySQL library that connects to an Amazon RDS.  The script initially connects to the RDS prior to running the function.  Inside the function, the MySQL on the RDS is queried, and then the Sys.sleep command is executed for a duration of 24 hours (86400 seconds) and then resumes.  Because Amazon's RDS wait_timeout parameter is set to 8 hours (28800) which results in this error in my R console:

```
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
    could not run statement: MySQL server has gone away
```

I cannot do this so I have tried the following code:

```
duration <- 86400
con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
       user = passwordFile$user[1],
       password = passwordFile$password[1],
       host = passwordFile$host[1],
       dbname = passwordFile$dbname[1])
query <- function(...) dbGetQuery(con, ...)
testing <- function(){
       test1 <- query("SELECT * FROM a_log")
       print(test1)
       dbDisconnect(con)
       Sys.sleep(duration)
       con <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
              user = passwordFile$user[1],
              password = passwordFile$password[1],
              host = passwordFile$host[1],
              dbname = passwordFile$dbname[1])
       test2 <- query("SELECT * FROM a_log")
       return(test2)
}
temp <- testing()
print(temp)
```

The test1 object prints fine.  However, I get the following error (even when I set duration to 1) when trying to print test2:

```
>Error in mysqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) : expired MySQLConnection
```

Is it possible to connect to a MySQL server.database outside of a function and then to disconnect within a function and then reconnect within the function?  Thank you!!

Comment: The basic problem in your code is that you create a `con` variable in the global workspace and use the global varible in the `query` function. In the `testing` function you are creating a new local (!) `con` variable then which is not used in the `query` function which still tries to use the global `con` variable. I guess a simple `con <<- dbConnect(...` in `testing()` should suffice to update the global `con` variable instead of the local one (see help for `?\`<<-\``)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without being able to actually try out this code, a possible problem is that you have two functions trying to manage one connection. It can help to separate tasks with functions: `connect_to_amazon` creates the connection, `query` returns a table, and `testing` wraps a process.

It's also risky to have functions reference values in a parent environment, since those can change or not even exist later.

You can have `query`, or any other function that accesses the Amazon database, use `connect_to_amazon` to make the connection, then `on.exit` to make sure the it's closed when the function's done.

```
connect_to_amazon <- function(password_file) {
  dbConnect(
    MySQL(),
    user     = password_file$user[1],
    password = password_file$password[1],
    host     = password_file$host[1],
    dbname   = password_file$dbname[1]
  )
}

query <- function(..., password_file) {
  amazon_con <- connect_to_amazon(password_file)
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(amazon_con), add = TRUE)
  dbGetQuery(conn = amazon_con, ...)
}

testing <- function(password_file) {
  test1 <- query("SELECT * FROM a_log", password_file = password_file)
  print(test)
  Sys.sleep(duration)
  test2 <- query("SELECT * FROM a_log", password_file = password_file)
  return(test2)
}
```

If you needed to do any other tasks with the Amazon database, you can either write another wrapper function (e.g., `write_amazon_table(..., password_file)`), or just call `connect_to_amazon` and work directly with the connection.

Comment: Nathan, that answer is the JAM!!!  And you are the MAN!!!

Thank you so much.  I know that was a difficult question to answer without having a database to connect to.  It works.  It works real well.

Thank you also for advice on functions referencing values in the parent environment.  I wish I could up vote this with more points to you.  This wasn't an easy question to answer in the abstract.

Comment: Nathan, would I have to write a function like the query function above if I were to change the last two lines of the testing function to a single line that reads: dbWriteTable(amazon_con, "a_log", test1, append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE) ?  THANK YOU

Comment: @Jonathan That was something I overlooked, so I've updated my answer.  I'm not a computer scientist, so any better advice for managing connections from experts is welcome.